# Point cloud Library Cluster Extraction

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, clusterpoint

I am using point cloud library, here I have made clusters of my cloud. 
Now I need to load clusters one by one in my program for further analysis

```
for (i=0; i<= total number of clusters ;i++)
{
    cloud=cluster_cloud_i;
    further processing ..
}
```

I am unable to find any method to load `cluster_cloud_i` , it gives me syntax error. For instance, I have two clusters named `cluster_cloud_1.pcd` and `cluster_cloud_1.pcd` .

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Are these 2 names identical, or second name had to be `cluster_cloud_2.pcd`? Could you post full error message? It would be better if you could include actual piece of code instead of pseudocode

Comment: The names are different as you have pointed out. i have figured out my mistake . the answer is 

ss << "cloud_cluster_" << i << ".pcd";
 reader.read<pcl::PointXYZ> (ss.str (), *cloud_cluster, 0);

Thanks for your time